# In C++ I'm not able to copy a string to another string using for loop. Why can't we copy this way in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I tried this code but temp is not getting anything in it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
string temp = "";
string psf = "abcd";
for(int i = 0; i < psf.size(); i++){
    temp[i] = psf[i];
}

cout << temp;
return 0;
}
```

While this way it's working absolutely fine.Why is it so?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
string temp = "";
string psf = "abcd";
for(int i = 0; i < psf.size(); i++){
    temp += psf[i];
}

cout << temp;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself, In `string temp = "";`, how many characters does that string have?  What would be `temp[3]`?

Comment: It's undefined behavior to index into an invalid location of a string. You could get any result from the first snippet.

Comment: Another question is what is wrong with simple `temp = psf;`? Why do you need loop?

Comment: *I tried this code but temp is not getting anything in it.* -- Change this: `temp[i] = psf[i];`  to this: `temp.at(i) = psf[i];` -- Now your program will stop dead, with an exception thrown telling you [the reason why](https://godbolt.org/z/6d69bfese).

Comment: OT:  In `string temp = "";`  you don't need the `= ""` part `string temp;` is sufficient